# (R lme4) Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate

Tags: r, regression, lme4

I am running a generalized linear model with random effects using the `glmer()` function from the package `lme4`.

The model code looks like this:

```
mod6 <- glmer((Ndifference+74337) ~ netm1011 + d1011 + 
           b0001 + (1|region), Family = Gamma(link = "identity"))
```

`Ndifference` is count data of population differences between 200 and 2010 of 50 states (and DC). There is one negative value (Michigan at -74336) so I added a constant to make sure my response was all positive.

All the predictors (aside from the random effect of region) are proportions or percentages. Netm1011 (rate of immigration to the states in 2010) and d1011 (rate of deaths per 1000 people) both have several negative values. B0001 contains all positive proportions (birth rate/1000 people).

When I run the model I keep getting this error:

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
(maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate
```

Before this error theres a crazy amount of output that looks like this::
[image: output before the error message above]

I've tried different families of distributions as well (`Gamma`, `inverse.gaussian`). What exactly does this error code mean?

Below is the data I've been using (just the variables involved). Any help would be appreciated!

```
structure(list(Ndifference = c(333269L, 86445L, 1245536L, 244720L, 
3333964L, 725062L, 166537L, 113590L, 33923L, 2791639L, 1484925L, 
151993L, 271526L, 404489L, 399906L, 122812L, 167087L, 299231L, 
74155L, 50624L, 477090L, 206187L, -74336L, 379644L, 120037L, 
392539L, 87578L, 117119L, 685035L, 76962L, 374381L, 243485L, 
409910L, 1481681L, 33444L, 178335L, 306232L, 408919L, 428717L, 
2533L, 612397L, 60714L, 654646L, 4296180L, 533538L, 16207L, 921089L, 
835264L, 46920L, 317348L, 70366L), d1011 = c(0.01009935290407, 
0.00482181820219, 0.00740624039708, 0.00988384227183, 0.00640323497813, 
0.00628209882119, 0.00812947210436, 0.00872837354861, 0.00764311417232, 
0.00915166624244, 0.00737517844004, 0.00718037578961, 0.00746442540795, 
0.00794410854005, 0.00889218497298, 0.00923607712106, 0.00850800517833,   
0.00983998039872, 0.00904860671746, 0.00978543746728, 0.00752488166029, 
0.00814412474047, 0.008998680863, 0.0074466124005, 0.00971662809766, 
0.00917030625948, 0.00880861178822, 0.00819753663997, 0.00718370505053, 
0.00796602176569, 0.00789025770533, 0.00777472712417, 0.00769648628539, 
0.00831202019281, 0.00850432185633, 0.00953304172455, 0.00962020831593, 
0.0084093843696, 0.00992588646267, 0.00893168396866, 0.00908595754594, 
0.00854178331167, 0.00947807131183, 0.00662702930588, 0.0053663066427, 
0.00848516414343, 0.00741560390799, 0.00724357008593, 0.01174960990152, 
0.00835051236548, 0.00772546941972), netm1011 = c(0.00109618827436, 
0.00189063449694, 0.00284535027555, 0.00218869215636, 0.00200262974559, 
0.0065388101588, 0.00074903204593, 0.00531214993154, 0.01546474398708, 
0.01046605886554, 0.00346226170766, 0.0039720759906, 0.00110199747387, 
-0.00340610876916, -4.63800737643485e-05, 0.00143230827182, -0.0018378102704, 
0.00157293366968, 0.00169295518939, 0.00086246831653, 0.00396682929054, 
0.00395032406919, -0.00265224491201, 0.00162162050201, -0.0011606066005, 
-0.00128783881235, 0.00364476878277, 0.00043559148624, -0.00024040613102, 
-0.00066598675772, -8.70119549428016e-05, 0.00073131738351, 0.0004310477698, 
0.00519235806746, 0.00995606223948, -0.00192862200551, 0.00257535479622, 
0.00452502363079, 0.00132008444764, -0.0033720597776, 0.00464986350895, 
0.00318540398886, 0.0036471909126, 0.00699275905022, 0.00104501002309, 
7.98829235871906e-05, 0.00428168852619, 0.00637386122264, 0.00108682812851, 
-0.00029879124879, -6.91039695800782e-05), b0001 = c(0.01800092688004, 
0.02011469070317, 0.02028566151573, 0.0179124206973, 0.01941521590629, 
0.01846852368848, 0.01564274610647, 0.01763088342656, 0.01782806190528, 
0.01595252071591, 0.02045645453128, 0.01934534979926, 0.01892079941012, 
0.01859074925398, 0.01759062061265, 0.01593436604294, 0.01809677718956, 
0.01698907749719, 0.01956008653302, 0.01292521854622, 0.01781296155008, 
0.01589757045382, 0.01700943508274, 0.01673888527351, 0.01999578814362, 
0.01689588730579, 0.01474826635901, 0.01762957227617, 0.01844433337313, 
0.01426185254875, 0.01647358935637, 0.01852101980912, 0.01705020482026, 
0.01867477359887, 0.01474757340631, 0.01722894148788, 0.01746963005864, 
0.01632960496522, 0.01466473971168, 0.01463956672595, 0.01772861915606, 
0.01702957873434, 0.01740538934663, 0.02136003322368, 0.02565897334663, 
0.01291107725161, 0.01753092898439, 0.01687893043972, 0.01409828681218, 
0.01588293753652, 0.01540482711573), region = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 4L), .Label = c("MW", "NE", "SE", "W"), class = "factor")), .Names =              c("Ndifference", 
"d1011", "netm1011", "b0001", "region"), class = "data.frame", row.names =    c(NA, 
-51L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a particular reason for using Gamma with an identity link (`family=Gamma(link="identity")`)? That's probably the proximal cause of your problem. Using Gamma with a log link (`family(Gamma(link="log"))`) seems to work fine. (As is often the case, fitting a log-Normal model, i.e. log-transforming the response variable and using `lmer` rather than `glmer`, is even faster and more robust.)

In general, using link functions that do not constrain the response to be in the domain of the chosen family is numerically unstable, because it is easy for the model to wander into infeasible regions. Translating that out of statistical jargon, if you're going to assume the data are Gamma-distributed, then you may have trouble if, on the way to the optimal solution, the program tries out values that lead to negative mean estimates. In contrast to the identity link (or the canonical inverse link for the Gamma family), the log link forces all the predictions to be positive.

`lme4` is admittedly more fragile than it could be about this, but I don't see any particular reason to assume your responses are Gamma distributed with an identity link ...

Based on what I'm seeing from the model predictions and diagnostics, it might be probably be worth dropping the negative value from your data set - forcing it to be (just barely) positive is making it an outlier on the log scale ...

```
library(lme4)
m1 <- lmer(log(Ndifference+74337) ~ netm1011 + d1011 + 
           b0001 + (1|region), data=dd)

m2 <- glmer(Ndifference+74337 ~ netm1011 + d1011 + 
           b0001 + (1|region), data=dd,
     family=Gamma(link="log"))
```

Comparing pred and obs (ignoring the outlier):

```
pairs(cbind(obs=log(dd$Ndifference+74337),
            lognorm=predict(m1),gamma=predict(m2)),gap=0,
      xlim=c(10,15),ylim=c(10,15))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was using the identity link more or less because I thought that the link would further over-complicate the actual model. I figured that the default link for Gamma was already log (although I may be wrong as lme4 and glmadmb have different defaults). Going back to how you said that log links forces all predictions to be positive, how is this possible when it's mathematically not possible to log negative values?

Comment: the default for Gamma is the canonical (inverse) link.  The linear predictor (b0+b1*x1+b2*x2+ ...) is transformed by the *inverse* link function, i.e. the exponential function in the case of log-link. So negative values map to predictions between 0 and 1.

Comment: understood, I ended up re-scaling the response variable to be a proportion as all my predictors we're also in proportions or rates. The percentage of population change was actually normally distributed. Ultimately OLS regressions (or linear mixed-effect models) ended up being rather effective. @Ben Bolker

Comment: If this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Bolker !